# Javascript. Обнуление переменных в цикле

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть код, который проходится по заказам и получает суммы за определенный период. Сейчас 3 периода. Почему-то все цены одинаковые на всех трех периодах.

Думаю, что где-то надо обнулять переменные, потому что они суммируются из прошлых периодов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся в коде. Спасибо.

```js
var periods = {
            "last7": [dateFormat(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"), dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")],
            "lastMonth": [dateFormat(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00"), dateFormat(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth(), getLastDayOfMonth(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() - 1)), "yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59")],
            "last30": [dateFormat(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"), dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")],
        };

        var ordersData = {}, purchase = {};

        for (var period in periods) {

            var orders = await this.apiOrders({
                "dateCreatedStart": periods[period][0],
                "dateCreatedEnd": periods[period][1],
                "statusCode": "40226"
            });
            for (var order of orders) {
                var numPositions = 0;
                var sumPositions = 0.00;
                var numOrders = 1;

                for (var position of order.positions) {
                    if (position.statusCode == "40226") {
                        numPositions++;
                        sumPositions += (position.priceOut * position.quantityFinal);
                    }
                }

                if (typeof purchase[order.userId] != "undefined") {
                    numOrders += purchase[order.userId].numOrders;
                    numPositions += purchase[order.userId].numPositions;
                    sumPositions += purchase[order.userId].sumPositions;

                }


                purchase[order.userId] = {
                    "numOrders": numOrders,
                    "numPositions": numPositions,
                    "sumPositions": Number((sumPositions).toFixed(2))
                };
                sumPositions = 0.00;
                numPositions = 0;
                numOrders = 1;
            }

            ordersData[period] = purchase;

        }

        console.log(ordersData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это подозрительная строчка:

```
ordersData[period] = purchase;
```

Вы всем `ordersData[period]` назначаете одно и то же.

```
    var ordersData = {}/*, purchase = {}*/;

    for (var period in periods) {
        var purchase = {};
        ...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @infosizhukcom Пожалуйста. Успехов.